# How to select multiple different colums and joins in a query depending on another column value?

Tags: mysql, join

I have an existing quite complicated request on table A where a `JOIN` is made on another tables B and C (and actually more).

I would like that on a specific value of a field in table A, fields are added to the `SELECT` but also different join(s).

I know that I can add columns dynamically with `CASE`, but the tested value is always the same, and I would like to avoid repeating a `CASE` for each field because there are many fields. (For clarity I named the tables "B" and "D" in the `CASE` but in the actual situation it could be the same with a join alias)

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN A.a1=1 THEN B.b1
    WHEN A.a1=2 THEN D.d1
  END AS a2,
  CASE
    WHEN A.a1=1 THEN B.b2
    WHEN A.a1=2 THEN D.d2
  END AS a3,
  CASE
    WHEN A.a1=1 THEN B.b2
    WHEN A.a1=2 THEN D.d2
  END AS a3,
  //... many others on different tables but always on the same condition
FROM A
  JOIN //?? if first condition join on B and C else on D and E
```

Is there a solution to join dynamically and avoid this long repetition of `CASE` calls?

NOTE: this is only a part of a query built with code, which makes it difficult to use `UNION` because fields are added elsewhere and that would be difficult to match the same number of selected fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use all `LEFT JOIN`s with your current `CASE` conditions as part of the `ON` and then `COALESCE` the values of those tables. Something like:

```
      SELECT COALESCE(B.b1,D.d1) AS a2,
             COALESCE(B.b2,D.d2) AS a3,
             COALESCE(B.b3,D.d3) AS a4,
             ...
        FROM A
   LEFT JOIN B ON {normal_join_condition} AND A.a1 = 1
   LEFT JOIN C ON {normal_join_condition} AND A.a1 = 1
   LEFT JOIN D ON {normal_join_condition} AND A.a1 = 2
   LEFT JOIN E ON {normal_join_condition} AND A.a1 = 2
```

Comment: note that it can take a little while before I answer, because it's complicated and I must test it in real case (cannot simplify it as there are other parameters). I also nedd to think a little because some fields can come as different names so I need to duplicate them

Comment: This should work with more `JOIN`s as well. If there were tables F and G joined on `A.a1 = 3` you could change the `SELECT` to `COALESCE(B.b1,D.d1,F.f1) as a2,` and so on. It is still a little messy but should be better than the required `CASE` to do the same logic

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that a previous test I made today did set values to  `NULL`, so that I couldn't realize it works. One of the `JOIN` in the original query was used to filter out some rows that didn't have an entry in the joined table, so I still need to test if using `LEFT JOIN` instead has an impact on this, but the answer is OK!

Comment: Well the rows that don't have the entry in the joined table are not filtered out anymore but i can cope with it because I should be able to solve it (in my case, it's tricky to add a `WHERE` condition but not impossible). If you already know a solution for this, feel free to add it, I still accept your answer

Comment: I would have to have more information about the rows that should be filtered out. If it does not impact performance too much, using a `HAVING` clause may be easier than `WHERE`. It depends on what you are needing to filter out though.

Comment: The request was a combination between a `JOIN` and many `LEFT JOIN`. The join made sure that there is an entry in table B (or in D in the new version, depending on the condition) for the rows selected from A, or else the row should not be returned. It works perfect with a `WHERE ({normal_join_condition_for_B} AND A.a1 = 1) OR  ({normal_join_condition_for_D} AND A.a1 = 2)`. Thanks for all!